# display flex not working when using display flex on parent container

Tags: html, css

I want to position the skills in a row using flex box. Applying display flex to the container should do it, butit doesn't work.

```css
.skills {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20rem;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
            <div class="skill">
                <h3>Main skills</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>Second</li>
                    <li>Third</li>
                    <li>Fourth</li>
                    <li>Fifth</li>
                </ul>
            <div class="skill">
                <h3>Secondary skills</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>Second</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing `</div>` tag for your first `<div class="skill">`. So it should look like the following...

```html
<div class="skills">
  <div class="skill">
    <h3>Main skills</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
      <li>Fifth</li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- this is the closing tag you're missing -->
  <div class="skill">
    <h3>Secondary skills</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It does work but I guess you have an error in your markup. The parent of the second .skill is the first .skill, not .skills

your markup

```
<div class="skills">
  <div class="skill">
    <h3>Main skills</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
      <li>Fifth</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="skill"> <!-- move this block -->
      <h3>Secondary skills</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- to here -->
</div>
```

To have flex applied, move the second .skill block after the closing div of the first one. Like this:

```
<div class="skills">
  <div class="skill">
    <h3>Main skills</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
      <li>Fifth</li>
    </ul>
  </div>  <!-- closes .skill --> 
  <div class="skill">
    <h3>Secondary skills</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- closes .skill --> 
</div> <!-- closes .skills -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code the div with skills class has only one child which is div with skill class, which is the reason flexbox is not working. Add `display: flex;` to the div with skill class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BUG-16</title>
        <style>

        .skills {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20rem;
        display:flex;
        }

        .skill ,ul 
        {

        display:flex;

        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="skills">
            <div class="skill">
                <h3>Main skills</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>Second</li>
                    <li>Third</li>
                    <li>Fourth</li>
                    <li>Fifth</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="skill">
                <h3>Secondary skills</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>Second</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it